# Macro/Script - Set Forward Blue Line as Reference to delete previous emails when forwarding without manually deleting the previous emails

Tags: vba, email, outlook, sendmail, forward

Seeking your insight on this process:

I want to forward the latest email received only not including the entire thread of the emails. Can I forward that email without manually deleting the previous emails on the thread?

I want to automatically send the NEWEST/LATEST emails received to a specific email address without the previous emails on the thread.

What I'm thinking is, I will set the "BLUE LINE" as reference, for starting position and ending position. Because as we all know, whenever we forward a HTML email, there's a blue line separating emails received.

Is it possible to do that? Set blue line as reference, then delete everything not inside the lines.

Comment: What code have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I'm still thinking if this idea is possible. I just don't know how can I set the Reply/Forward blue line as starting and ending references.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the message body at runtime using VBA macros. The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to customize the message body.

If you are new to VBA macros, see [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).